# tar a whole subfolder and a single file from another subfolder, retaining directory structure?

Tags: tar

Most q&a about tar either ask about grouping an entire directory into a `tar`, or single files matching a pattern (e.g. same extension), but I want to do a mix of both.

That is, if I have this dir structure:

```
SomeDir/someFile1.a
SomeDir/someFile2.b
SomeDir/someFile3.c
SomeDir/...
SomeDir/someFileN.xyz
fileInRoot.abc
OtherDir/someFile.xyz
OtherDir/theFile.f
```

I want to tar the `SomeDir` completely, and the single `theFile.f` alone, so that, when I decompress it in another server, I'm left with this dir structure:

```
SomeDir/someFile1.a
SomeDir/someFile2.b
SomeDir/someFile3.c
SomeDir/...
SomeDir/someFileN.xyz
OtherDir/theFile.f
```

Is this possible? Which flags to tar should I use?

Comment: try `tar -cvf test.tar SomeDir OtherDir/theFile.f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you can simply pass directory/files names to tar.

```
 tar -cvf tarfile.tar SomeDir/ OtherDir/theFile.f
```

Upon extracting:

```
[user]$: ls
OtherDir  SomeDir  tarfile.tar

[user]$: tar -xf tarfile.tar

[user]$: ls SomeDir/
someFile1.a  someFile2.b  someFile3.c  someFileN.xyz

[user]$: ls OtherDir/
theFile.f
```

Comment: perfect thanks! can't upvote because I'm new :-S